# Calculate a point normal to a line

Tags: java, geometry

I have a line L specified by (x1,y1)(x2,y2) and want to calculate the 
coordinates of the point that is:

- located on the normal that intersects L at the half of its length
- is a certain distance D away from L

Examples:

- If the line is (x1,a)(x2,a) (horizontal) the coordinates of the 
  calculated point would be ((x2-x1)/2,D).
- If the line is (a,y1)(a,y2) (vertical) the coordinates of the calculated
  point would be (D, (y2-y1)/2).

But i dont know how to calculate the coordinates in a generic way for all
lines regardless of the angle (-Pi to Pi).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it should be tagged as HomeWork

Comment: It might help us decide if this is a programming question or not if you show us the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The center between both points is given by

```
((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)
```

while the (unnormalized) normal is

```
(-(y2-y1), (x2-x1))
```

If we normalize this vector we get

```
(-(y2-y1), (x2-x1)) / sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
```

and if we combine both we find the two points

```
((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2) +- D * (-(y2-y1), (x2-x1)) / sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
```

which both fulfill your requirements.